# Reuse Wordpress Category

Tags: wordpress

My blog has a category slug `podcast` that was changed from `entcast` some time ago.

Today, I want to reuse the `entcast` slug, but I can't create a category with this name, since wp says me there is already that one. I think wp keeps an old registry, just like it does for the post history.

My questions are:

1. What should I do to reutilize the `entcast` slug?
2. Is there some risk of losing data with that?

As I do think this change should be done in database itself, so this is why the second question.

Comment: did you checked your categories admin page to see that it is really deleted ??

Comment: Off couse. And it was not deleted, but renamed (the slug was renamed).
I just want to use the old slug in new category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check in wp_terms in your WordPress database to see what category uses this slug. Beware that all categories use terms (this is why the database table is called wp_terms). And a term is basically the association of a Name (display name) and a slug (ID name).
So if no category uses the slug "entcast" it does not mean that the slug is not used by another taxonomy (like tags, for example). The best way to be sure is to check the wp_terms table in your WordPress MySQL database. If another taxonomy uses the same slug, you will have to go to each and every taxonomy that uses this slug and change it so it becomes "free" again. See this image to illustrate WordPress use of terms and taxonomies:
[image]

Comment: Perfect! This is the best answer I could wait for. Thanks.

Comment: Just found that I had a tag with the same slug. I renamed it so I could use again in the category - no touch to database was needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in admin, click on Posts > Categories. Browse to your podcast category. Click on Edit to edit it. The slug field will most probably be "entcast" altough the Name field is "podcast". Change the slug field (to "podcast" if it is available). Then you will be able to create an "encast" category.

Comment: As I said on question, the Slug was changed, not the name.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility you get the WordPress message you are saying is if you are using a category name that is identical to an existing category name with the same parent. (Otherwise, please post the exact WordPress message you get). So if you want to use a slug that was previously used but is not anymore (you can check if it still exists by looking at the content of wp_terms in your WordPress database), you can perfectly do it by typing any category name that is not already used for the same parent (this is of logical necessity) and by manually specifying the slug if it does not correspond to the name itself. There is no reason why this should not be possible. 
If this answer does not solve your problem, please :
1) check in wp_terms to be sure that the 'encast' slug does not exist anywhere (I mean is not already attached to a certain category name)
2) post the exact WP error message you get so we know exactly if it is a category name or a category slug problem.

Comment: When I add a new category with a specific slug (ex. "entcast"), the slug is prefixed with the parent category (ex. "podcast-entcast"). If there is no parent, it is postfixed with an index (ex.: "entcast-2"). In either cases, I can't rename the slug ("The slug 'entcast' is already being used by another term").